# Reservation Budapest Munich Night train EN 462

Tags: trains, tickets, bookings, budapest, deutsche-bahn

While booking this ticket at Deutsche bahn website, it says "Subject to compulsory reservation (Salzburg Hbf --> München Hbf), 2nd class only seated accommodation , Comfort ticket (IRT Integrated Reservation Ticket) (Hegyeshalom(Gr) --> Salzburg Hbf)"

Does it mean that I need to do seperate reservation? If yes from where can I do it?

Comment: Yes, you need a reservation. Getting a reservation is part of the regular ticket purchase process on bahn.de. Since it's compulsory in your case, you shouldn't be able to select "no reservation" (as you can do when buying a ticket for a regular long distance train), but I have never bought tickets for a train with compulsory reservation so I won't post this as an answer, as it's only an educated guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do the booking on the Deutsche Bahn website, you should not be able to book a train with compulsory reservation without reservation. In these cases reservation usually is included in the regular fare and doesn't cost an extra 4.5€ as with other tickets.

You can check on your ticket. If a wagon and seat are mentioned, you have your reservation. There should be a note like "ICE 123, 1 Sitzplatz, Wg. 22,
 Pl. 24, 1 Gang, Tisch, Nichtraucher, Handy, Res.Nr. 8123 4567 8901 34" including the reservation number, wagon (22) and place (24).

If you booked a full price ticket and want to use another train, you have to change the reservation.

In general, you can get a reservation on most trains by going through the normal booking process and select "reservation only" when asked during the process. (There are trains that can not be reserved (regional trains mostly) and some that can not be reserved online (some international connections))

Comment: As this is an international train (from Budapest to Munich), I had tried to reserve a seat as you have mentioned, but as it is international journey it says it's not possible. Then what should I do to reserve a seat for it? Does it incur additional charges on this route?

Comment: @Nikhil Are you really sure that you don't have a reservation on the ticket? I just checked on the website, I don't see a way to book an EN without reservation.